# How to know the interfaces or methods if I don't know the name of them in Java?

Tags: methods, interface

If I don't know there exists an interface or method in Java and I have to write one by my own.
How can I avoid this? (It takes much more time to write a method by myself.) How can I find a method which I even don't know the name of it?

Comment: You search google for the thing that you want the method to do?

Comment: What if I find it hard to search cause I don't know how to describe the function of some methods?

Comment: Keep trying till you can describe it. Look at the results for your bad description, and pick out keywords to find a better description.

Comment: After searching Google, you ask on Stack Overflow: "How do I frob widgets in Java?", preferably with some text like "I expected to find a static method for this in the Widgets utility class, but there isn't one; I Googled for 'frob widgets java' but the results were about frobbing gadgets instead".  Do _not_ ask for a library that does it -- your question will be get closed as _off-topic -> request for off-site resource_.  Answerers will use appropriate libraries on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Are you worried that you might create an interface or method with a duplicate name?

If so, the answer is to use "packages"

EXAMPLE:

```
package com.mypackage;

interface myInterface {
  public void myMethod ();
}
```

Here is a good tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Comment: I mean I might take a lot of time to write a method and then I find that the method has already been in some existing JAVA package.. I can just use it directly.

Comment: If you want to find existing code that might already do what you need to do ... then, as Eric said: "You search google for the thing that you want ... to do". And when you do write your own classes and interfaces ... be sure to create a meaningful package name for them!